# Non-printable input is not handled correctly in GDB

Tags: c, gdb, scanf

I'm experimenting with buffer overflow vulnerabilities and have a given (compiled) C program which uses `scanf` to read data input by the user into a buffer without necessary overflow prevention checks in place. I believe I have almost figured out how to exploit this but I'm currently failing to debug my approach because I cannot figure out how to pass non-printable input characters to the vulnerable program while debugging it using `GDB`.

From reading the documentation and other answers on here this should be easily possible by writing the input bytes to a file and then passing that file as input to GDB like so: `(gdb) r < input.txt`. But strangely enough, when I then check the contents of the vulnerable buffer in memory after the call to `scanf`, its contents are completely different from the input byte sequence, except for the first byte (which is `\xa1`). I have tried the same thing with a file containing only ASCII characters and in that case, the buffer contents after the call to `scanf` match the file contents.

I'm at a loss here, could this be a GDB issue? Or some `scanf` peculiarity? (I don't have the C program's source code).

EDIT: I have added the result of `hexdump -C input.txt` below.

```
00000000  a1 0d 84 04 08 e0 ff 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |................|
00000010  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  90 90 90 90 90 90 90 90  |................|
*
000000d0  48 d6 ff ff 48 d6 ff ff  0a                       |H...H....|
000000d9
```

Comment: Is your input containing any zeros?

Comment: Or newline characters? Or even whitespaces? What the `scanf`  line looks like? What your input looks like?

Comment: I have added the hexdump above, there is a newline at the end but no zeros or newlines otherwise. Also, the same thing happens when I input seemingly arbitrary non-printable characters with e.g. `(gdb) r <<< $(python -c "print('\x...')")`.

Comment: Here you go. `0x0d` is a newline character (CR) which is terminating the input for `scanf` (if it is something like `scanf("%s"...)`.

Comment: Huh, I didn't think about that, that might be it. In that case, would it be impossible to write that specific byte into the buffer?

Comment: With such a `scanf`? No.

Comment: Okay, thank you. I think that cleared things up (on second inspection my "arbitrary" test input did always include a `0x0d` byte).